# Snowball Stemmer Usage

Tags: java, stemming, snowball

I'd like to use the stemmer here for merging word counts.
http://snowball.tartarus.org/download.html
The page has a download link, but I'm not sure how to integrate the files into my eclipse project
Its not just a jar to drop into my lib folder, its a file system.
Does anyone know of some documentation explaining this, as I didn't see any on the website.
(As in, what do i import, how do I call it etc..)

Comment: [The snowball manual](http://snowball.tartarus.org/compiler/snowman.html) and [The snowball how to run it](http://snowball.tartarus.org/runtime/use.html)

Comment: i've read both of those, but the second one says how to run it standalone with java, not how to import into a project and the first one doesn't touch on real setup

Answer (score 16):

Build the jar file and add it to your Build Path.

Details:

- Download the tgz with the code from here
  http://snowball.tartarus.org/download.php
- Uncompress.
- Go to libstemmer_java directory and read README.
- Follow instructions to compile (using javac).
- You might have to correct or remove java/org/tartarus/snowball/ext/frenchStemmer.java because it has an error and doesn't compile.
- Create jar file: Go to libstemmer_java/java directory then 
  jar cvf libstemmer.jar *
- Add libstemmer.jar to your Build Path (in Eclipse: Project-Properties-Java Build Path-Libreries Tab).

Then you can use the stemmers doing something like:

```
import org.tartarus.snowball.ext.spanishStemmer;
...
spanishStemmer stemmer = new spanishStemmer();
stemmer.setCurrent("torero");
if (stemmer.stem()){
    System.out.println(stemmer.getCurrent());
}
```

Comment: I ran into a compile error so I took out all but the English language packs and the compiling went perfect. Thank you for actually answering this question and not telling someone to RTFM. :)

Comment: i am having an unusual problem . i got my string in a variable called "word" like word="torero"; and when i pass this variable to to the stemmer it wont work. eg stemmer.setCurrent(word); stemmer.stem(); System.out.println(stemmer.getCurrent()); .it wont get stemmed. tell me what i am doing wrong here .

Comment: No @JunaidShirwani. It sometimes return wrong output. Same thing happening to me.